# Could not load type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.StringResourceManager' from assembly 'Microsoft.Office.Server.Search

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, error

I have a SharePoint 2010 site that has been running for about 4.5 years now with absolutely no problems until now. It is a very basic site, mainly used for storing files. It's mostly stock - there is only one small piece of custom code.

The site worked without any issues until about a week ago when all the sudden it fails to load and displays an error:

> Could not load type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.StringResourceManager' from assembly 'Microsoft.Office.Server.Search, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'.

This happens immediately when hitting the root page, as well as when I try to go to the Central Admin page. I found a longer error message in the Event Viewer which I have added to the end of this post.

I'm not a SharePoint guru and I've run out of ideas on how to troubleshoot this.

So far I have tried:

1. Check IIS - IIS is started, app pools are running, etc
2. IIS reset
3. Check Event Viewer - nothing relevant other than what I posted
4. Check Windows Update - no recent updates
5. Restart server
6. Check
   'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\80\App_GlobalResources' 
   I do see an Office.Server.Serach resx file. (but not a DLL, is that
   normal?)
7. Googled the error - I did not find anything yet that seems relevant. Most suggestions are regarding custom code that uses the search, and suggest fixes to that the custom code. This doesn't seem to be the case for me. Our custom code does not use Office Search, or even have a reference to that library. Also, our custom code is just a web part that is on one page (not the main page). When it breaks it doesn't take the whole system down (well, it hasn't in the past)

My questions for the community are:

1. Is anyone familiar with this error?
2. What else should I check?
3. Should I just reinstall SharePoint and restore from a backup? (this is fine I guess... but, if possible, I'd rather know what went wrong and how to fix it.)

I appreciate your time and help.

Full error from Event Viewer:

```
Event code: 3005 
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
Event time: 6/14/2017 2:35:13 PM 
Event time (UTC): 6/14/2017 7:35:13 PM 
Event ID: 594dc40ea273457186e3c3cf4c23c88b 
Event sequence: 9 
Event occurrence: 2 
Event detail code: 0 

Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/891918418/ROOT-1-131419416668677779 
    Trust level: WSS_Minimal 
    Application Virtual Path: / 
    Application Path: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\80\ 
    Machine name: CHIEF 

Process information: 
    Process ID: 8748 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE 

Exception information: 
    Exception type: TypeLoadException 
    Exception message: Could not load type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.StringResourceManager' from assembly 'Microsoft.Office.Server.Search, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'. 

Request information: 
    Request URL: http://zzz.yyyy.com/SitePages/Home.aspx 
    Request path: /SitePages/Home.aspx 
    User host address: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
    User: zzz\aaaa
    Is authenticated: True 
    Authentication Type: NTLM 
    Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE 

Thread information: 
    Thread ID: 17 
    Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE 
    Is impersonating: False 
    Stack trace:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.SocialNotificationControl.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)


Custom event details:
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having just about the same issue.  It started about 10 days ago.  However, we can access the site, there are just no search boxes and the error you mention comes when trying to access CA.  Get-SPServiceApplication returns no search service. It just disappeared.  Not sure how to resolve.  Going to run configuration wizard first and go from there.  Let me know if you got anywhere with it.

Comment: Unfortunately I have not made any progress.